Let's create a Facebook page for cogsci.SE
In reply to other questions about how we can promote the site and thereby solve a score of our current problems,
I suggest we create a Facebook page for CogSci.SE
What for?
The majority of students are on Facebook. Many have created groups for their university, department or class. If one of these "likes" our FB page, we'll have a lot of exposure among our target audience.
How to?
All we would need are some nice images (profile and header) and a concise description that attracts the relevant target audience. The images could be free stock images, meaningful graphics (like an intelligence bell curve) that we could create ourselves and discuss here (on meta or in chat), or screenshots of the site header, if we have nothing else. 
The profile picture could be of our most attractive member, on which we could hold a vote ;-P
If we want, we should be able to integrate the two sites so that new questions automatically appear as posts on the FB wall. I wouldn't post each answer. This would be an automatic process that takes no effort or time, once it is set up. If we want to go beyond that, we could manually select choice questions or answers, or wait with posting until questions have been reviewed and edited (some questions need this to be representative). Ideally questions asked on FB would appear here automatically as well, and be answered here.
Your opinion?

StackExchange on Facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange

Some Stackexchange sites on FB:

https://www.facebook.com/StackIslam
https://www.facebook.com/scifi.SE


If we create such a FB page, we'd need to use an email address that all the moderators have access to (and no one else).

Interesting, but wonder what SE headquarters stance on something like this would be. Might be some issues with copyright laws and such ... on the other hand, just extending our social network beyond SE I don't really see a problem. I would be hesitant of moving over content though.

How do we get their opinion?

I think they've been okay in the past as long as you don't claim to be an offical group or use their logos

Not using logos would be uncool. We want to support their site, not ourselves. Is there a way to ask?

I have asked for guidance on this in the teacher's lunge @what. So far I have been told by other mods not to use the logo...

Seems like meta-SO would be the place to go with a proposal like this...if Josh's page is at all potentially problematic?

At the very top of this page, to the immediate left of the words "StackExchange", there is a small version of the SE logo. A larger version can be seen as profile image in the official SE FB page (linked in the question).

I started this a long time ago but wasn't able to finish it. Here is the page. It needs a lot of work...
If anyone would like to help take this over for me, send me a note or comment/answer here. I had good intentions when I started this but don't use facebook very much and haven't had the time to devote to this.
I can add other administrators to the page, so any registered facebook user can help add content to this page. However, I am not sure what the most official, best way to add users would be. Maybe if you want to admin this page, you post here and if the community upvotes you, then you're granted admin access? Suggestions here are welcomed.

Cool. But I feel I don't want to do this alone or in a team of two. I don't mean setting up that page, I'm ready to invest some time in that, but rather the decision and support. We need more than you and me wanting it and Steven finding it interesting. It has to be done with the backing of the community. --- So I have said my part, I'm ready and willing to do some hard work on it, and now I wait what you moderators and some of the other respected users have to say.

I agree wholeheartedly @what, let's see what others say here on Meta.

My question remains though, what will, and can we put on there?

Time for another meta-question, IMHO! Either that, or we should first make sure the answer to the first question here (i.e., "Way ahead of ya!") is legit, as per the concerns @what expressed in his answer.

I just wrote to Josh asking him to ad me as admin, so I can install an app that will post the recent questions from cogsci.SE to "our" FB page. The next step should be to decide on some kind of design for that page (profile and header image) and write some sexy site description. Do we want to discuss that here, or open a new meta question? Or elsewhere. Chat is not ideal because of time zone differences.

I think that's a great idea :-)
But:

Every moderator (and maybe some of the major users) need to support this idea
It would be great to have official support for this, so we should at least ask


So far I see support from two mods...@JeromyAnglim? Other mods passing through lately that we should tag here (e.g., AnaHevesi, Jaydles, Shog9)...? I'm behind you all 100% too FWIW! Certainly won't be "a team of two" if you're stepping up with me to help Josh's page.
